# Manipulating text files with python

Tags: python

I have a task to open file `input.txt`, which contains two lines:

```
100-50
50-25
```

Then I need to perform subtraction (evaluate the given expresions) and write them in `output.txt`. The output should look like this:

```
100-50=50
50-25=25
```

So far I have this:

```py
with open('input.txt','r') as file1:
    x=file1.read()
    print(x)
```

But I don't know how to proceed with evaluating given input.

Comment: Can you explain please how to do?

Comment: [Try using something like this `print(eval('31+41-59'))`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/)

Comment: @GiorgosXou No, don't use `eval`. Never use `eval` unless you have no better option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: I totally forgot how insecure and "dirty" of a solution it is,  thanks for mentioning it, my fault

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for line in lines:
            sub = int(line.split("-")[0]) - int(line.split("-")[1])
            f2.write(line.replace("\n", "") + "=" + str(sub) + "\n")
```

Comment: Since you're using a context manager to open `f1`, you don't need to call `f1.close()`. You should simply move the next block out of the context manager, i.e., `with open('output...` and the rest should be outdented one level. Same thing with `f2`, `f2.close()` is superfluous when using a context manager (i.e., a `with` statement).

Comment: Thanks a lot, nicely explained! Really appreciate.

Comment: Louis I can't explain how helpful it was, and really nicely explained, very easy to understand. After all I guess Python is not so scary.

Comment: I don't think this is useful.  This code doesn't work for any expression that isn't in the form `<number> - <number>`.  For example, other binary operators, unary operators (e.g. a leading `-`), more than one operator in an expression, operator precedence, brackets, etc. It is impractical to use this approach with more complicated expressions.  If this all that the OP needs ... OK.  But then this answer is unlikely to help anyone other than the OP.

Comment: Thanks to joanis's comment. Actually don't need to use `close()` function.